# ajax not running after var data = json_parse(msg.d);

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

This is the first time i am playing with Ajax. I am trying to just create a basic login at the moment. Anyways i have the following script..

```
     <script language = "javascript">
            function Login() {  

                       $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.aspx/Login",
                        data: '{' +
                                'username:"' + $('#username').val() + '",' +
                                'password:"' + $('#password').val() + '"' +
                               '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(msg) {
                            alert("alert1");
                            var data = json_parse(msg.d);
                            alert("alert2");
                            if (!data.error) {
                                alert("No Error);
                            }
                            else {
                                alert(data.error);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(msg) {
                            alert('Failure: ' + msg);
                        }
                    });         

            }
    </script>
```

For some reason it does not run anything after var data = json_parse(msg.d);

It shows the first two alerts but noting after.

the ajax page has the following `

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Login(string username, string password)
{
    return "{\"error\": \"No IDs\"}";
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped-through this with a debugger? Maybe `data` isn't being parsed properly? Hence, no access to `error`, therefore a chain reaction of failure. Just a thought.

Comment: hmmm im not testing it locally on a web server so dont have a debugger

Comment: Javascript is executed locally, and IE has a debugger (which is its only saving grace, IMO.)

Comment: my url where im trying to test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats inside the function `json_parse`?  That function could be the source of your error.
A better method to parse JSON is like this.

1. [Go to Douglas Crockford's Github JSON-js/json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and copy it
2. Minify it at [jscompress.com](http://jscompress.com) and copy the compressed code ( can skip this step )
3. Paste it somewhere in your Application folder as json2.js
4. Now reference the script at the page you are pulling data from
   `<script src="path/to/script/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
5. Now inside the function, parse your JSON like this.
   `var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);`

On an un-related side note, its better if you change your `error` like this to catch errors effectively.

```
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert(xhr.statusText);
}
```

Also, call `WebMethod` like this.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Login(string username, string password)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    obj.error = "No IDs";
    string str = js.Serialize(obj);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, JavaScript doesn't have a built-in `json_parse()` function.  Unless you've defined that yourself, it's probably throwing a JavaScript error.  The standard client-side utility available in newer browsers is `JSON.parse()`

More importantly, you've got some redundant serialization going on there.  When you're working with ASP.NET ScriptServices and PageMethods, it's important to [let ASP.NET's built-in serializer do the work of converting your response to JSON](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).

Right now, your WebMethod is returning a mess of doubly serialized JSON that looks something like this:

```
{d:{\"{\"error\": \"No IDs\"}\"}
```

Since you've set your `dataType` to `json`, jQuery is already running a JSON parse operation before your success or error handlers run, but it's only converting the first level of JSON to a JavaScript object.  Unfortunately, that only gets it to the point that `.d` contains yet another JSON string.

If you let ASP.NET do the work for you, you could use something like this in the WebMethod instead:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Login(string username, string password)
{ 
  return "No IDs";
}
```

And then, things will go more smoothly on the client-side:

```
success: function(msg) {
  if (!msg.d) {
    alert("No Error);
  } else {
    alert(msg.d);
  }
},
```

If you really want to retain `error` as the key for the error message, you can do something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object Login(string username, string password)
{ 
  return new { error = "No IDs" };
}
```

Or, even use a defined class:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
  public string error { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static ErrorResposne Login(string username, string password)
{ 
  var response = new ErrorResponse();

  response.error = "No IDs";

  return response;
}
```

In either of those latter cases, you can access the error text through `msg.d.error` once it hits the client-side.